# Meaning of apache2 CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT and CONTEXT_PREFIX?

Tags: apache, cgi

How are the Apache2 (2.4) CGI environment variables `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `CONTEXT_PREFIX` defined?

From experimentation, I've determined the following:

- **`CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT`** appears to be the full local path to the original request when `DirectoryIndex` or `ErrorDocument` call a CGI script.
- **`CONTEXT_PREFIX`** appears to be the original `REQUEST_URI`, sans any query part, when `DirectoryIndex` or `ErrorDocument` have called a CGI script. (In these cases, `REQUEST_URI` is set to the URI of the CGI script, rather than the original.)

However, I can't seem to find any official documentation from Apache on these variables. Does anyone here have a link to such documentation, or more authoritative knowledge to share?

Answer (score 6):

`CONTEXT_PREFIX` and `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT` tell you how apache used an `Alias` directive (or similar feature - like `mod_userdir`) to translate the URL path to the file system path.  The file system path will end up pointing to the the file to be served or a cgi script to run.

So, if apache translates the URL:

```
    http://host/_CONTEXT_PREFIX/path/file
```

to the file system path:

```
    /_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT/path/file
```

it implies there is an `Alias` (or `ScriptAlias` or similar mechanism such as `mod_userdir`) like the following:

```
    Alias /_CONTEXT_PREFIX /_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT
```

The `Alias` directive saves */_CONTENT_PREFIX* in `${CONTEXT_PREFIX}` and */_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT* is saved in `${CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}`.

Here is one example of using it.  In a `<Directory>` context `RewriteRule` translates a path name relative to the directory to a absolute URL path, or an absolute file name (which must exist).  So if you wanted to translate URL's that ended in .htm to .php,  you would have to write it like this:

```
    <Directory "/_CONTEXT_DOCMENT_ROOT">
        <FilesMatch "*.htm">
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteRule (.*)[.]html$ /_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT/$1.php
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
```

Now you can write it without repeating `/_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT`, but perhaps more importantly the file does not have to exist because we are rewriting it to a URL path:

```
    <Directory "/_CONTEXT_DOCMENT_ROOT">
        <FilesMatch *.htm>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteRule (.*)[.].* ${CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$1.php
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
```