# check if file exists in subdirectories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an include file that contains a Rewrite which checks if a semaphore file exists, if not display a maintenance page.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^/ http://mydomain/maintenance.html  [L]
```

Normally it works, but I have now a VirtualHost with several applications answering on different context roots:

- mydomain/app1
- mydomain/app2
- etc.

If I change the rule for each apps is working.. but since the number of applications are already a lot, and may increase, I need to create a single rule for all, something like this, where xxx can be any:

```
<Location /xxx>
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/xxx/maintenance.enable -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^/ http://mydomain/maintenance.html  [L]
</Location>
```

ps. I'm using latest apache 2.4 version

Comment: And what is your actual question/problem now …?

Comment: That I would like to create a single include file which match all the context roots, something like this (which obviously doesnt work):
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{CONTEXT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f

Comment: And what it `%{CONTEXT_ROOT}` supposed to be? (Are you actually talking about a setup similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/25751834/1427878 here?)

Comment: sorry I updated slighly my first question, hope it's more clear. Basically "xxx" can be any of the applications running under the main domain (mydomain/app1, mydomain/app2, etc.)
Yes is similar to that, but I'm not sure I understood what is the value of CONTEXT_PREFIX and how to use it in my case.. did a couple of tests, but all were unsuccessful

Comment: That only seems to apply if you are using aliases or stuff like that. From your description it is not clear if you have anything like that set up, or if “application” simple means “content of a specific directory” here.

Comment: I have several locations, one for every applications.. Inside the location I do different things, usually, but not always, proxy somewhere else

Comment: Well you would need to somehow extract the `xxx` part from the actually requested URI ... You can refer back to a match from the RewriteRule in a preceeding condition using `$N`, so I would try to match that part in the rule, `^/([^/]+)` or similar, and then insert this match in the condition in the value you want to perform the check on, `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/maintenance.enable` (Since you want this for all of those, it must not be placed in a specific Location section any more.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution similar to what I wanted initially using a macro like this:

```
 <Macro check_maintenance $context>
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$context/maintenance.enable -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html
 RewriteRule ^/ http://mydomain/maintenance.html  [L]
 </Macro>
```

And in the vhost configuration added outside the Location directives:

```
 use check_maintenance app1
 use check_maintenance app2
```